# Aligning texture

Tags: texturing, procedural

How to make texture look same scale on side of the cylinder as on it's top?

[image]

Comment: The texture is  in object space, so it should look the same, with your mapping. Ctrl-A apply the scale of your object. It must have been scaled down in its 'up' direction in Object Mode, so the Object is carrying a non-uniform scale in its transform.  If you scale in Edit mode, you scale the mesh with respect to the object, rather than the object itself.

Comment: Ow, i forgot about it...
Thank you)

Comment: Further reading: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7349/3710

Answer (score 4):

Many things can reduce the side texture distortion.

The easiest thing to try *would* be to apply scale. (Go to object mode, **Object > apply > scale**.)

If this doesn't work though, another thing to try would be to select all of the faces in edit mode, and scale it along an axis in the image editor, so that it "undistorts" the texture on the side.

As this would pretty much ruin the effects of the *Smart UV project* if you are using that to unwrap. It would be a last resort.